# Connect to Exchange 2013 with powershell while disconnected from network

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I have restored a version of my exchange 2013 server to a virtual machine. I want to do some work with it but I don't want to bring it online. When I try to connect to it with powershell it gives me errors like:

> WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode
>   0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are
>   currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

How might I get connected so I can run my normal commands through powershell without connecting the server to the network?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Domain Controller for authentication. How did you logon to the machine?

Comment: With domain credentials.

Comment: Yeah, cached ones.
If you want to play with exchange, you may install a lab with dc & exchange.
What is your goal? Playing around? Doing some kind of recovery?

Comment: Recovery first and playing around after the recovery. I was hoping there was a way to connect with local credentials or cached domain credentials.